# What is the difference between these two offsetof macros?

Tags: c++, macros

I saw these two macros of offsetof:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && !defined(_CRT_USE_BUILTIN_OFFSETOF)
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define offsetof(s,m) ((size_t)&reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>((((s*)0)->m)))
#else
    #define offsetof(s,m) ((size_t)&(((s*)0)->m))
#endif
#else
    #define offsetof(s,m) __builtin_offsetof(s,m)
#endif
```

What it the difference between :

```
((size_t)&reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>((((s*)0)->m)))
```

and :

`((size_t)&(((s*)0)->m))` ?

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` defends against overloaded unary `&`.

Comment: @T.C.: Make that an answer!  (In fact, it is *the* answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`operator&` can be overloaded in C++. If there is a user defined overload for `operator&(const M&)`, where `M` is `decltype((s*)0)->m)` (i.e. the type of the member) and if the overload does not return the address of the object, then the macro without the reinterpret cast would not behave correctly.

`char` reference is probably used specifically because `char` and `unsigned char` have [special guarantees](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) about being allowed to alias any type and because operators cannot be overloaded for primitive types. `const volatile` qualifiers are there probably so that the compiler does not issue a warning about casting away those qualifiers if the member happens to have them.

As T.C pointed out in a comment, the extra cast is probably there to protect against user defined overloads. C does not have overloading, so the protective cast is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`reinterpret_cast<type>(expression)` is an [expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) which tells the compiler to treat the series of bits given in the expression `(((s*)0)->m)` as type `<char const volatile&>` instead of the original type. They still operate on the same data, only the compiler treats the data as a different data type in the top expression.

Comment: The question is what the difference is between the two macros and (implicitly) why there are two different ones, not what a cast is.